# need to access header attribute on html5 video source url

Tags: javascript, prototype

this is my problem.

I have a video tag, whose src is an url. Like this:

```
var video = $('video');    ///using prototype js framework
video.setAttribute('src',
    'aNiceUrl');
```

The problem is that i need to get some data from the video HTML header, but i dont know how to get it. I need to get the data in the same moment i get the video, cant do more requests to `'aNiceUrl'`. The data doesnt have to come in the header, i simply need a way to get it. Any ideas?

BTW, i can see the data with firebug on the net tab, any ideas of how is he doing that?

Comment: If possible can you show us what firebug shows so we can get a better idea of what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any data of what `<video>` tag is receiving from the given url by the means of Javascript.

Your best option is to include that data in the original page or to make 2 requests (1 for `<video>` tag, and the other for ajax request).